# Create a struct of non stated properties

Tags: go

I am coming from javascript and know about objects:

```
{}
```

and I know that ytou can set a property that was not stated in the object:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.myProp = "TEST";
```

In go, I know that there is a thing called a struct

```
type MyStruct struct {}
```

is there a way to set `MyStruct.MyProp` even when it is not inside the struct?

Comment: The reason it works in JavaScript is because JavaScript is dynamic. What you are looking for is a map. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19

Comment: I would highly recommend at least going through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). It covers all the language fundamentals and only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go is a statically typed language, so you can't do that.

The structure you might be looking for is Map.

Even when using maps, you must define the types of keys and values, and these cannot change.
Example:

This defines a map with integer keys and string values

```
mymap := make(map[int]string)
mymap[2] = "This is a string"
```

This defines a map with string keys and interface{} values

```
mymap := make(map[string]interface{})
mymap["somekey"] = struct{}{Name: "John", Age: 30}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the map as a parameter in a `func`?

Comment: Yes there is, here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/HHj6UDKogte

Comment: a pedantic note perhaps, but using `make(map[T]T)` is not exactly idiomatic go. It's far more common to see either `map[int]string{}` (creating a literal), or perhaps pre-allocate the size of a map: `make(map[int]string, 10)`. The advantage being that a map literal allows you to initialise it to contain some values already, and `make` with a size allows you to optimise runtime allocations